# How to solve ientitychangetracker?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity

```
var 
     studentClassNumber=DContext.Instance().StudentEntities.tblStudentInformation.ToList();
        DContext.Instance().StudEntities.tblStudentInformation.AddRange(studentClassNumber);
        DContext.Instance().StudEntities.SaveChanges();
```

**

Add tables to the database from the database.But I get an error in the many to many relations tables.This error is:

**an entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of ientitychangetracker.**

and I take error row

```
DContext.Instance().StudEntities.tblStudentInformation.AddRange(studentClassNumber);
```

Comment: You could create a context for the old database, fetch it, move the data into the new context object and save. If this is a one time thing you might just use SSMS import.

Comment: Hi.I want to use entities.I would like to import tables from the old database with entities.How can I get data with entity?Thank you.

Comment: Make (or reverse engineer) a context for the old database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database